# Entity graph from stored procedures or table valued functions WITH parameters

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, entity-framework-5

Can either EF or NHibernate can handle the following scenario?

- Assume a data model with tables A and B, mapping to entities A* and B*
- Entity A* contains 0..n child entity B*s
- Table B contains a foreign key to the id column of table A

So far, this is ORM 101 but now it gets trickier:

- Either table valued functions or stored procedures must be used to access the database
- Calls to either must include two additional parameters

  - e.g. assume an integer and a datetime2

Is there a way to pass in the two extra parameters so that EF or NH can add them in turn to the calls it makes to populate the object graph?  The output of the TVFs or stored procedures can be modified as necessary, so I don't think I'm asking the same question as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953855/mapping-select-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework) but could be mistaken.

Can either of these tools accomodate this scenario?  It would be better not to have to compose the object graph manually, which seems like the logical plan B.

Update: jbl (thank you) suggested this [link](http://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate), which gets us half way there.  It shows how to load a collection of simple entities from a parameterized TVF. However, I am trying to do something a little more complex. In my case

(1) I need to load child entities and

(2) the query/TVF for the child entities also needs to be passed the same two parameters

The nut of my question is "what is the best/correct way to do this?" Is there a way to configure either of these tools to populate the object graph for me as they both can do in the simple query-based case?

Comment: I guess this can be done with NH mapping by code (though I never tried that) Do you need to do the mapping on application start, or later in the lifecycle. Also, do you need to have several views running at the same time in the same app (products/sales for 2011 AND products/sales for 2012) ?

Comment: The underlying tables I am querying are multi-dimensional.  As a result I need to pass in 2 parameters to pull out the appropriate "rows" to populate the object graph.

Comment: On second thought, I guess what you are looking for is called filtering in NH : http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters